# error when i try to do an insert on SQLite Android Studio

Tags: java, sql, android-studio

I don't know why i get an error when i do a insert in my SQL DB, the code that create the table is  :

```
 mydatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TabellaSpese.TABLE_NAME + "(" + TabellaSpese.PRIMARYKEY + " INTERGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + TabellaSpese.IMPORTO + " LONG," +
            TabellaSpese.CATEGORIA + " TEXT," + TabellaSpese.DATA + " DATE," + TabellaSpese.NOTE + " TEXT);");
```

and the query is:

```
 ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(TabellaSpese.IMPORTO,importo);
    cv.put(TabellaSpese.CATEGORIA,categoria);
    cv.put(TabellaSpese.DATA,UsefullFunction.getDate());
    cv.put(TabellaSpese.NOTE,note);
    return mydatabase.insert(TabellaSpese.TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
```

the error is :

```
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting note=d data=13/01/2020 importo=5 categoria=arova
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Spese has no column named note (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1]): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Spese(note,data,importo,categoria) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
```

I can't find the error

Comment: "table Spese has no column named note" - so, does it?

Comment: furthermore i try to update the version of the db but with the same result

Comment: if you made changes on the table like adding a column or renaming it, you should create the upgrade version of it or simply uninstalling / clear data your app.

Answer (score 0):

It’s seems that you should create migration to new version of database. Not just increment its version